# Has anyone used a 'Dr Robot' platform with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm investigating indoor/outdoor capable platforms and stumbled upon a Canadian robotics manufacturer that has some [seemingly "rugged" platforms](http://jaguar.drrobot.com/) that output a "communication raw protocol" for talking to linux PC payloads (like an ubuntu ROS machine)

Has anyone used one of these? Are there existing ROS bindings?

They list first class support for a number of software development SDKs, so creating some bindings shouldn't be too hard--I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone has already gone through the trouble.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29790/has-anyone-used-a-%27dr-robot%27-platform-with-ros?/) by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1607 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-11-08**:
Did you notice that they claim to support ROS? (e.g. http://jaguar.drrobot.com/specification_V4.asp). Maybe they have developed some code as well.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-25**:
Hey Jeff, I am currently using a Dr Robot platform with my research. I'm using the H20 model with ROS and I've augmented their jaguar4x4 ROS code to work with the robot. If you have any questions, I'll try to help as best I can. Otherwise the manufacturers are quite helpful too!

**Comment by [Mughal_786](https://answers.ros.org/users/22157/mughal_786/) on 2015-05-12**:
@MartinW. I wanted to ask. whether do you have a repo regarding H20 platform on github?
Would be great help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not personally used any Dr.Robots platforms.

However, I remember answering a question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/54277/joint_trajectory_action/) related to a DrRobot H20 platform.  So you may try contacting @MartinW if you have questions.

A quick google search also turned up [this](http://code.google.com/p/drrobot-ros-demo-base/source/browse/?r=4#svn%2Ftrunk) repository of example ROS interface code.  It looks like this code may even be a "semi-official" example (uploaded by a drrobots.com user-email).  *Note: the latest repository version is missing all the files.  Use the r4 release to see the latest versions.*

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-25**:
Damn, looks like I accidentally downvoted your answer yesterday, can't revert that back as it's a "older vote".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know my friends of [Team TEDUSAR](http://www.tedusar.eu/cms/en/content/german-open-2012-result) use a Jaguar and they run ROS on it. Might be helpful to ask them.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1